# How multiple consumers from different consumer groups read from same partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use case where i have 2 consumers in different consumer groups(cg1 and cg2) subscribing to same topic(Topic A) with 4 partitions. 
What happens if both consumers are reading from same partition and one of them failed and other one commited the offset?

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka the offset management is done by **Consumer Group per Partition**.

If you have two consumer groups reading the same topic and even partition a commit from one consumer group will not have any impact to the other consumer group. The consumer groups are completely discoupled.

Comment: How can i make sure that those consumers read same data? If suppose one consumer has reset the offset to read from some previous location then both consumer will read different data at a time.

Comment: As said, if you have two consumer groups they are completely encapsulated from each other reading the data independently from each other. I am wondering why you would need two different consumers doing the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Let's say if i want to achieve this scenario. What design do i need to follow for that?

Comment: Can you explain more about the background? What is the purpose of those two Consumers? If I understand correctly you just need one Consumer doing two different things and committing the offset only when those two things are done.

Comment: There's no background for this, I just want to understand if it's possible to create this use case

Answer (score 1):

One consumer of a consumer group can read data from a single topic partition. A single consumer can't read data from multiple partitions of a topic.

**Example** Consumer 1 of Consumer Group 1 can read data of only single topic partition.

Offset management is done by the zookeeper.

**__consumer_offsets:** Every consumer group maintains its offset per topic partitions. Since v0.9 the information of committed offsets for every consumer group is stored in this internal topic (prior to v0.9 this information was stored on Zookeeper).

When the offset manager receives an OffsetCommitRequest, it appends the request to a special compacted Kafka topic named __consumer_offsets. Finally, the offset manager will send a successful offset commit response to the consumer, only when all the replicas of the offsets topic receive the offsets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simultaneously two consumers from two different consumer groups(cg1 and cg2) can read the data from same topic.

In kafka 1: Offset management is taken care by zookeeper.

In kafka 2: offsets of each consumer is stored at __Consumer_offsets topic

Offset used for keeping the track of consumers (how much records consumed by consumers), let say consumer-1 consume 10 records and consumer-2 consume-20 records and suddenly consumer-1 got died now whenever the consumer-1 will up then it will start reading from **11th record onward**.

Comment: So, In kafka offset is mainted at consumer level. Right?

Comment: Consumer group level